Specflow second scenario always return 500 internal server error
I have a feature file with two similar scenarios:
Feature: MachineLearningFeature

@api

Scenario: Successfully retrieve default machine learning settings
    Given User is authorized as 'Admin'
    And Settings were not changed after system deployment
    When A 'GET' call is made to '/api/machinelearningsettings'
    Then The response status code should be 200

@api

Scenario: Successfully retrieve machine learning settings lists
    Given User is authorized as 'Admin'
    And Settings were not changed after system deployment
    When A 'GET' call is made to '/api/machinelearningsettings'
    Then The response status code should be 200

This is a StepDefinitions of these scenarios.
[Binding]
public class MachineLearningSettingsSteps : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>> 
{
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;
    private HttpClient _client;
    private HttpResponseMessage _response;

    public MachineLearningSettingsSteps(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = _factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions());
    }

    [Given(@"User is authorized as '(.*)'")]
    public void GivenUserIsAuthorizedAs(string role)
    {
        // Clear previous headers if any
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Role");
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Role", role);
    }

    [Given(@"Settings were not changed after system deployment")]
    public void GivenSettingsWereNotChangedAfterSystemDeployment()
    {
    }

    [When(@"A 'GET' call is made to '(.*)'")]
    public async Task WhenAGETCallIsMadeTo(string endpoint)
    {
        _response = await _client.GetAsync(endpoint);
    }

    [Then(@"The response status code should be (.*)")]
    public void ThenTheResponseStatusCodeShouldBe(int expectedStatusCode)
    {
        _response.StatusCode.Should().Be((HttpStatusCode)expectedStatusCode);
    }
}

The first scenario always works and the second also when it is separately. But when it runs together second scenario always fails. There are some conflicts with the HTTP client state or something else.

The error is:
 Expected _response.StatusCode to be HttpStatusCode.OK {value: 200}, but found HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError {value: 500}.

Why does this happen? How to fix this?

You will need to inspect the response from the server. Nothing looks blatantly wrong with your steps. You might have done what a test should do: discover a bug with the System Under Test.
